# My Global Variable Deleted Automatically in Qt C++ GUI

Tags: c++, qt

```
typedef struct{
    QString text;
} MySt;
MySt myStList[3] = {{"first"},{"second"},{"third"}};
// ↑Global value

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        qDebug() << (myStList+i)->text;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Above Result is `"first" "second" "third"`.
But, I'm getting a segmentation error (core dump) when I try to run My Qt C++ GUI Program.
(same logic. segmentation error occurred before qDebug Output.)

Core dump Backtrace:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0002b5a4 in QArrayData::data (this=0xdb3460e2)
    at /usr/local/lib/Qt5.6.2_ARM/include/QtCore/qarraydata.h:53
53          Q_ASSERT(size == 0
```

When I got the error, I try display Many List on GUI. and, There are two ways to solve the problem:

first, remove List on GUI. (display List Count 50->5)

second, edit code like this:

```
typedef struct{
    QString text;
} MySt;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MySt myStList[3] = {{"first"},{"second"},{"third"}};
    // ↑Local value

    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        qDebug() << (myStList+i)->text;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why fixed it by change My Global value to Local value. Displaying Many List affect RAM and removed Global value automatically?(Qt 5.1.2)

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] of the failing program and [edit] your question to show it. It's impossible to do anything but guess if you only show working code.

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't use array indexing `myStList[i]` instead of `(myStList+i)`?

Comment: Thanks for Comment. I solved it. My GUI Program inserted over 100byte value, into `UCHAR buf[64];` when GUI display many List.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Before My GUI Program display list, It try insert list to buffer(`UCHAR buf[64];`) .
So Segmentation error occurred after display it(when list value has more than buffer). I have to change buffer.